# Import-SPWeb - Feature 'ReportServer' is deployed but its version '14.0.0.0' is below the miniumum required version of '15.0.0.0'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

I am trying to import a site from my production to test environment but am getting the error below.  I've run psconfig but this hasn't upgraded the feature.  Any advice on what I need to do to upgrade the "ReportServer" feature?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should always make sure that your source and destination farms have the same configuration. To resolve your issue you'll need to reconfigure your reportserver wsp. To do that you can use the existing wsp and deploy it in 14,15 compatibility mode.

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity contoso_solution.wsp -GACDeployment -CompatibilityLevel {14,15}
```

Comment: Hi Taran, thanks for the tips.  I had thought my farms were the same.  There are no solutions in CA> Solution Management called "ReportServer" so I have no idea where the .wsp would be and I have no recollection of deploying it.  

I had assumed this related to SSRS?  My recollection was installing the SSRS Service, creating the SQL Service Application and installing the Reporting Services Features "Reporting Services - SharePoint" and "Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Products" on the SP boxes.  I used the same steps for both my dev and prod farms.

Comment: Just to add to this - on my Dev environment, if I go to C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES - I can see ReportServer there.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it by uninstalling "SQL Server 2014 RS Add-in for SharePoint" on each SP server and installing again.  Not sure if this would be normal procedure by my ReportServer Feature is now version 15

Answer (score 0):

We suffered the same problem. But we saw we had installed RSSharepoint SQL 2012. We installed RSSharepoint SQL 2014 without remove old version and problem persist, all steps with Sharepoint Reconfig.
At last we uninstalling "SQL Server 2014 RS Add-in for SharePoint" with reconfig and restart the server and installing again. Now it works correctly.